# how to Pass extras to a fragment from a compose function in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

how to Pass  extras to a fragment from a compose function in Android Jetpack Compose

This is the compose function

I want to send "extra" data from the function to the fragment

```
@Composable
fun SomeComposeView(){
     
    AndroidViewBinding(SomefragactBinding::inflate) {
        val myFragment = fragmentContainerView.getFragment<SomeFragment>()
        
   }
```

in fragment I want to get it as

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    int i = bundle.getInt(key, defaulValue);
}
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? There doesn't seem to be a way to do this currently.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your .xml file, add `FragmentContainerView` without adding `android:name'.

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

2. In Composable function,

Get current activity instance using `val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity`

And then inflate the fragment dynamically as normally with fragment manager by passing arguments.

```
AndroidViewBinding(SomefragactBinding::inflate) {

            activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.fragment_container,
                InboxFragment::class.java,
                bundle,null
            ).commit()
            // ...
        }
```